Solve the circuit with variable capacitance
I want to know the procedures/techniques which will give analytical solution for the source current with variable capacitor and constant inductor, connected in series with AC voltage source as shown below. A technique with Solution will help a lot. Thanks in Advance

++
tried to get the differential equation in terms of source current. But not able to get rid off integration. Vs = Ldi_s/dt+1/c(t) integral(i_s) dt. upon differentiating on both sides, Vmwcos(wt) = L*i_s + d(1/c(t))/dt *  integral(i_s) dt + 1/c(t) * i_s. As seen second term still contains integral term . Further differentiation, creates the term with integral.

What have you tried already? Where are you stuck?

tried to get the differential equation in terms of source current. But not able to get rid off integration. Vs = Ldi_s/dt+1/c(t) integral(i_s) dt. upon differentiating on both sides, Vmwcos(wt) = L*i_s + d(1/c(t))/dt *  integral(i_s) dt + 1/c(t) * i_s. As seen second term still contains integral term . Further differentiation, creates the term with integral.

That needs to be edited into the question, it should not be in the comments.

Are you looking for the AC steady state solution

Yes. Looking for steady state solution.

How or when does the capacitor vary? What is the (1+cos(2wt)) term telling us?

@tharunmeddi Looking for steady state solution ... again, that needs to be added to the question,  it should not be in a comment

Are you looking for the AC steady state solution – Andy aka

Yes. Looking for steady state solution

The impedance of the circuit is \$j\omega L + \dfrac{1}{j\omega C}\$.
The current is simply voltage divided by impedance i.e. \$\dfrac{V}{j\omega L + \dfrac{1}{j\omega C}}\$.
I'm not sure that there's much else to do other than plug in some numbers. Yes, it's slightly complicated by the formula for the capacitor but, it's still a case of plugging in numbers into a spreadsheet.
